# No program updates in 16.04?

Tags: updates

I've been using Ubuntu for years and I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04. Since upgrading to 16.04, I occasionally get a pop-up message saying that there are program updates available but when I run sudo apt-get update it seems like there are no updates available. However, when I run sudo apt-get upgrade I'm able to install a bunch of updates. I haven't been able to see and install updates with the update command since I upgraded to 16.04, what's up with that?

Comment: In Windows you 'update' programs, in Ubuntu you 'upgrade' programs. Because upgrading programs makes them better, and updating them (in Windows) just gives you more headaches (more viruses, security updates making even more vulnerabilities, non-cumulative updates that you have to install one-by-one, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never have. `apt update` only updates the package lists from the Ubuntu repositories. `apt upgrade` then upgrades the packages.